# Не устанавливается rubocop под Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby

Всем доброго времени суток. Изучаю RoR. Сейчас начал под виртуалку ставить rubocop (вводил команду:
sudo gem install rubocop
Сразу система выдала ошибку: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rubocop:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/ext/jaro_winkler
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20191222-31972-1jpyajw.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.4/gem_make.out
Честно говоря, в тупик поставило, что я делаю не так и как это исправить

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, вам не хватает заголовков самого руби:

```sql
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential ruby2.3-dev
```

Тут же убеждаемся, что стоит пакет `build-essential`.